# Previously working Laravel App fails on new Deployment to Heroku

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

I have a previously functioning app deployed on Heroku. Made some changes and tried deploying to heroku to no avail. Deployment fails after encountering this connection refusal. I have checked all DB Credentials and they are accurate for production. I'm not entirely sure of my packages though and trying to be careful since it's an inherited codebase and I'm kinda new to both PHP and Laravel.

```
remote:        > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
remote:        > @php artisan package:discover
remote:
remote:        In PDOConnection.php line 31:
remote:
remote:          SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
remote:
remote:
remote:        In PDOConnection.php line 27:
remote:
remote:          SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
remote:
```

Here's my full deployment trace:

```
Enumerating objects: 48, done.
Counting objects: 100% (38/38), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (22/22), done.
Writing objects: 100% (22/22), 17.18 KiB | 2.86 MiB/s, done.
Total 22 (delta 15), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> PHP app detected
remote: -----> Bootstrapping...
remote: Deprecation warning: require.test-hook is invalid, it should have a vendor name, a forward slash, and a package name. The vendor and package name can be words separated by -, . or _. The complete name should match "[a-z0-9]([_.-]?[a-z0-9]+)*/[a-z0-9]([_.-]?[a-z0-9]+)*". Make sure you fix this as Composer 2.0 will error.
remote: Deprecation warning: require.test-hook is invalid, it should have a vendor name, a forward slash, and a package name. The vendor and package name can be words separated by -, . or _. The complete name should match "[a-z0-9]([_.-]?[a-z0-9]+)*/[a-z0-9]([_.-]?[a-z0-9]+)*". Make sure you fix this as Composer 2.0 will error.
remote: -----> Installing platform packages...
remote:        - php (7.4.3)
remote:        - ext-gd (bundled with php)
remote:        - ext-mbstring (bundled with php)
remote:        - apache (2.4.41)
remote:        - nginx (1.16.1)
remote: -----> Installing dependencies...
remote:        Composer version 1.9.3 2020-02-04 12:58:49
remote:        Deprecation warning: require.test-hook is invalid, it should have a vendor name, a forward slash, and a package name. The vendor and package name can be words separated by -, . or _. The complete name should match "[a-z0-9]([_.-]?[a-z0-9]+)*/[a-z0-9]([_.-]?[a-z0-9]+)*". Make sure you fix this as Composer 2.0 will error.
remote:        Loading composer repositories with package information
remote:        Installing dependencies from lock file
remote:        Package operations: 87 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
remote:          - Installing kylekatarnls/update-helper (1.2.0): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing symfony/polyfill-util (v1.14.0): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing symfony/polyfill-php56 (v1.14.0): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.14.0): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing paragonie/random_compat (v9.99.99): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing symfony/polyfill-php70 (v1.14.0): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.14.0): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v3.4.37): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts (v1.1.7): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v4.4.4): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing psr/log (1.1.2): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing symfony/debug (v3.4.37): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v3.4.37): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v2.6.1): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing symfony/css-selector (v4.4.4): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles (2.2.2): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing symfony/var-dumper (v3.4.37): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing symfony/routing (v3.4.37): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing symfony/process (v3.4.37): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing symfony/finder (v3.4.37): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing symfony/console (v3.4.37): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing symfony/polyfill-php72 (v1.14.0): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-idn (v1.14.0): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing symfony/polyfill-iconv (v1.14.0): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing doctrine/lexer (1.0.2): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing egulias/email-validator (2.1.17): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v6.2.3): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing ramsey/uuid (3.9.3): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing psr/simple-cache (1.0.1): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing psr/container (1.0.0): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing symfony/translation-contracts (v1.1.7): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing symfony/translation (v4.3.11): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing nesbot/carbon (1.39.1): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing mtdowling/cron-expression (v1.2.3): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing monolog/monolog (1.25.3): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing league/flysystem (1.0.64): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing erusev/parsedown (1.7.4): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing doctrine/inflector (1.3.1): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing laravel/framework (v5.5.48): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing asm89/stack-cors (1.3.0): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing barryvdh/laravel-cors (v0.11.4): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing symfony/filesystem (v4.4.4): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing seld/phar-utils (1.1.0): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing seld/jsonlint (1.7.2): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing justinrainbow/json-schema (5.2.9): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing composer/xdebug-handler (1.4.0): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing composer/spdx-licenses (1.5.3): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing composer/semver (1.5.1): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing composer/ca-bundle (1.2.6): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing composer/composer (1.9.3): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing ezyang/htmlpurifier (v4.8.0): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing luketowers/purifier (3.0.6): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing devdojo/chatter (0.2.18): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing doctrine/cache (1.10.0): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing doctrine/event-manager (1.1.0): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing fideloper/proxy (3.3.4): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing fzaninotto/faker (v1.9.1): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing guzzlehttp/promises (v1.3.1): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing ralouphie/getallheaders (3.0.3): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing psr/http-message (1.0.1): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.6.1): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-color (v0.2): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing nikic/php-parser (v4.3.0): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter (v0.4): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing dnoegel/php-xdg-base-dir (v0.1.1): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing psy/psysh (v0.9.12): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing laravel/tinker (v1.0.10): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing mtdowling/jmespath.php (2.5.0): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (6.5.2): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing aws/aws-sdk-php (3.133.23): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 (1.0.24): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing sdkcodes/lara-paystack (1.0.2): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing spatie/laravel-sluggable (2.1.6): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing larapack/hooks (v1.0.9): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing larapack/voyager-hooks (v1.2.2): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing doctrine/dbal (v2.9.3): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing larapack/doctrine-support (v0.1.9): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing intervention/image (2.5.1): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing arrilot/laravel-widgets (3.13.0): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing tcg/voyager (v1.3.1): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing test-hook (v1.0.0): Cloning v1.0.0 from cache
remote:          - Installing cloudinary/cloudinary_php (1.16.0): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing thedarkkid/cloudinary-flysystem (dev-master d44d07c): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing namshi/jose (7.2.3): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing lcobucci/jwt (3.3.1): Loading from cache
remote:          - Installing tymon/jwt-auth (1.0.0-rc.5.1): Downloading (100%)
remote:          - Installing willvincent/laravel-rateable (1.07): Loading from cache
remote:        Package mtdowling/cron-expression is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use dragonmantank/cron-expression instead.
remote:        Generating optimized autoload files
remote:        Carbon 1 is deprecated, see how to migrate to Carbon 2.
remote:        https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-carbon-2
remote:            You can run './vendor/bin/upgrade-carbon' to get help in updating carbon and other frameworks and libraries that depend on it.
remote:        > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
remote:        > @php artisan package:discover
remote:
remote:        In PDOConnection.php line 31:
remote:
remote:          SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
remote:
remote:
remote:        In PDOConnection.php line 27:
remote:
remote:          SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
remote:
remote:
remote:        Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
remote:  !     WARNING: An error occurred during a database connection or query
remote:
remote:  !     ERROR: Dependency installation failed!
remote:  !
remote:  !     The 'composer install' process failed with an error. The cause
remote:  !     may be the download or installation of packages, or a pre- or
remote:  !     post-install hook (e.g. a 'post-install-cmd' item in 'scripts')
remote:  !     in your 'composer.json'.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Typical error cases are out-of-date or missing parts of code,
remote:  !     timeouts when making external connections, or memory limits.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Check the above error output closely to determine the cause of
remote:  !     the problem, ensure the code you're pushing is functioning
remote:  !     properly, and that all local changes are committed correctly.
remote:  !
remote:  !     For more information on builds for PHP on Heroku, refer to
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support
remote:  !
remote:  !     REMINDER: the following warnings were emitted during the build;
remote:  !     check the details above, as they may be related to this error:
remote:  !     - An error occurred during a database connection or query
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !   Push rejected to travvapi.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/travvapi.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/travvapi.git'
```

**Edit**

CLear all config caches and this issue will be solved as stale configs have a way of lingering in the project.

Comment: It looks like your database configuration isn't correct. Are you using Heroku Postgres, or something else?

Comment: Thanks Chris. Using MySQL with ClearDB. Checked the configurations and it all seems legit. Though suspecting a potential space issue as the problem. Heroku weirdly uses space to define MySQL free tier limits and uses rows for Heroku Postgres which II am much more familiar with.